# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. LINE API

Tags: javascript, https, http-headers

I get this error when trying to access a LINE api, check  [here](https://developers.line.me/web-api/integrating-web-login-v2). 
And this is my code:

```
return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.line.me/v2/oauth/accessToken',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        params: {
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            client_id: channelId,
            client_secret: channelSecret,
            code: authorizationCode,
            redirect_uri: CALLBACK_URL
        }
    })
```

I tried on postman and it works. What should I do now?